# Can not fill gas into tank for 2004 Honda pilot

Tags: honda, fuel-system, fuel-tank, pilot

My 2004 Honda Pilot has a gas filling problem.  I have to fill it very slowly in order for it fill the tank.  Other wise it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

This could be a bad vent valve or a blocked vent hose located near the vapor canister under the vehicle.

As [this article](http://www.samarins.com/glossary/vent-valve.html) states,

> A clogged up vent valve can cause trouble filling the gas tank.

Another Pilot owner posted at [Car Gurus](https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/Discussion-c3844_ds694601) that "*when I try and put gas in, the pump keeps stopping as if the tank is full*". His resolution was a blocked vent.